# wordpress missing images give 404 but invalid folders give 500

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

Our wordpress (multisite) install gives a 404 error for references to missing images

but if you edit the url and make it have an invalid folder name, it gives a 500 error.

I assumed anything missing - either a missing image (file) or a folder should in either case give a 404

Is there anything common that would cause it to respond with a 500 instead?

Comment: Is there anything useful in the error logs? Do you have access to the DOM Logs?

Comment: Check image folder permissions. it may cause.